# How to jump to previous and last cursor in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, editor, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How to jump back and forward through the cursor position history in Sublime Text?

I google a lot and find [BufferScroll](https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll). But it doesn't work for me. I can't find any shortcut or how to use it in the document.

Update:

Every time I try to use Jump Forward (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>), my editor always says "Already at the newest position" while actually not in the newest position. Jump Back (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) works well.

Comment: How do you know it's not in the newest position? Can you produce a list of steps to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: this is a known bug for at least Ubuntu Linux, see comment below for link

Comment: @david.barkhuizen which link?

Comment: @user2635088 http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=66465

Comment: I'd like to post a new answer, reopening would be cool!

Answer (score 192):

If you mean jumping back and forward through the cursor position history, then in Sublime Text 3 it's [built in](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-beta-3019) via the GoTo menu or keyboard shortcuts:

> Jump Back and Jump Forward – Jump Back allows you to go to previous
>   editing positions. This goes hand in hand with Goto Definition: you
>   can now inspect a symbol definition, and quickly jump back to where
>   you were previously. Jump Back is bound to **Alt+Minus** by default.
>   The menu entry is Goto > Jump Back

There are plugins available for ST2, for example [navigationHistory](https://github.com/timjrobinson/SublimeNavigationHistory).

Comment: Thanks,but every time I try to use Jump Forward,my editor always says "Already at the newest position" while actually not in the newest position.Jump Back works well.

Comment: On Macbook it's Control+- "^-", fwiw

Comment: While (from other users comments) the Windows & Mac versions do not appear to be affected, at least the Ubuntu Linux build (14.04, Sublime 3 build 3065) has the following problem:  jump forward (i.e. Alt + Shift + -) does not work, with the editor reporting:  'already at the newest position'.  The bug report is available here:  http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=66465

Comment: ST3 built-in only has history size 1 for cursor position;   https://github.com/timjrobinson/SublimeNavigationHistory is better since it has unlimited history (works with ST2 and ST3)

Comment: And if you want to change the default keymap to your own, add the following in Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap

` 
{ "keys": ["ctrl+1"], "command": "jump_back" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+2"], "command": "jump_forward" },
`

Comment: has anyone else noticed the built in navigation history is absolute garbage? It seem to only navigate back to where you last CLICKED the MOUSE???

Comment: On Mac: go back: `Ctrl+-` go forward: `Ctrl+Shift+-`