# How to undo/redo user operations?

Tags: sublimetext3, undo

The situation is:

- Open a file
- Drag minimap to the middle of this long file
- Click somewhere on the line I want to edit
- Intend to press <kbd>Home</kbd> to go to the head of the **line**.
- Accidentally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>
- Am taken to the head of the **file**.

**QUESTION**

Is there a shortcut to return to the line I want to edit?

Comment: Sounds like you want soft undo; if you're on Windows/Linux, press `Ctrl+u`; if you're on MacOS it's `Cmd+u`. Add `Shift` to either key binding (depending on platform) for soft redo.

Comment: @OdatNurd That's exactly what I'm looking for! thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to jump to previous and last cursor in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996878/how-to-jump-to-previous-and-last-cursor-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 4):

From the creator of Sublime Text at https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/soft-undo/307

> Undo/redo in Sublime Text normally only steps through actions that modify the buffer, skipping over those that simply modify the selection. **Changes to the selection are still part of the undo history**, and can be stepped through using **Ctrl+U/Ctrl+Shift+U (softUndo/softRedo commands)**. These key bindings aren't displayed in the menu, and I'm wondering if anyone has discovered them on their own.
>
> I rarely use them myself, but did today, so it got me wondering if anyone else does

Change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the above to <kbd>Cmd</kbd> if using a Mac.